# Displaying now() data in seperate day/month/year sections?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I am using a now() code to enter just a date into the database. The date appears as Year/Month/Day  (yyyy/mm/dd).

In my PHP code I have been using:

```
$news_date=$row['news_date'];
```

to recall the date on my site, I was wondering, instead of the date all showing at once, is there a way to add a separate value for day, month and year? So I could recall 'day' separate and so forth? Obviously without changing the database to have 3 different inputs, there must be an easier way? I am fairly new to PHP and MySQL so if someone could help me out with an example that would be handy! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a very powerful function called `strtotime()` that intuitively converts next to any datestamp into a UNIX-based timestamp, which you can then format any way you want.

```
$news_timestamp = strtotime($row['news_date']);
```

Now you can use PHP's `date()` function to output this timestamp in all sorts of ways.

```
print 'Today is day number '.date('d', $news_timestamp); // 20
print 'The month is '.date('F', $news_timestamp); // March
print 'Post timestamp: '.date('l, F d, Y @ h:ia', $news_timestamp); // Thursday, March 20, 2014 @ 03:46pm
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for your help with that, I really appreciate it. Still have a lot of basic stuff to cover. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. There are many other ways to do this (and possibly more performant/optimized ways), but I like the flexibility of `strtotime`.